# why doesn't git track my directory?

Tags: git, gitignore

I made a .gitignore file as belows:

```
## all files
*
## keep track
!bin
```

bin is a directory.
However, if I make or change a file in the bin directory, it is not tracked at all.
How can I fix it?
I have also tried '!bin/*' and '!bin/**'.

Answer (score 4):

Since `*` matches both `bin` itself and everything inside it, and Git doesn’t track empty directories, you need to exclude both of those:

```
*
!bin/
!bin/**
```

If you only meant to apply this sort of stuff to the same level as the `.gitignore`, a leading slash is needed to indicate that:

```
/*
!/bin/
```